# Protection against IP attacks

Tags: ip, tcp

I wonder if an attacker sends a frame with an ACK flag to my boss' computer (for example) and then uses the broadcast IP to infect all the network, how could we protect against something like that?

I am the last voice on it department but I really wonder on how to protect computers against it.

Comment: I think you need to explain your attack scenario. What do you expect will happen of an attacker does these things?

Comment: This would all be so much easier if everyone just went ahead and implemented support for [RFC 3514](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3514.txt) on both ends of IP links. It's been around since 2003 and there's *still* no widespread support for such a simple, yet massively useful in the real world, feature.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think so... But there's a lot of infraestructure to implement the Security Flag and it would involve a lot of money to implement correctly the RFC 1750 algorithms in all of it. I also think i is just a pitty that companies interests are not on that

Answer (score 3):

> ..sends a frame with an ACK flag...

I assume that you mean a TCP packet with the ACK bit set in the TCP header.
As long as this packet does not belong to any existing connection it gets simply discarded. Belonging to the connection means that source and destination IP and port match and also the sequence numbers are within a small window of previously received packets.

> ... and then uses the broadcast IP to infect all the network

I'm assuming that you still talk about the same "frame". First, broadcast does not work for TCP at all, i.e. a TCP packet with a broadcast address inside will be discarded.

But even if you use UDP instead of TCP (which means no ACK flag since this does not exist for UDP) the attacker has to be in the same network already since broadcast will only work inside the local network. And, no sane system would reply to a packet which has a broadcast address as source, so it gets discarded and your idea of attacking all systems via broadcast will not work. Still, if the attacker in the local network anyway he can directly attack these systems.

Comment: Minor nit, but the source and destination IP addresses are at the IP level, not TCP or UDP. The IP packet then contains a TCP or UDP or something else packet which has the idea of port numbers (and e.g. in the case of TCP sequence numbers). Compare e.g. [IPv4 header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) and [TCP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I did not claim that IP addresses are at the TCP level or inside the TCP header. In my opinion I did not even talk about the different layers at all. I've only said that source and destination IP (and port and sequence numbers) of **the packet** must match and not at which layers of the OSI or TCP/IP reference models these information reside because this is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: I was mainly responding to your statement about "a TCP packet with a broadcast address inside", but I agree I could have been more clear. Anyway, it's not a big issue.

Comment: That is what I was wondering about: if the attacker is inside the network, how could we fight against an attack with the broadcast adress? I apologize by the way, I should have been more specific...

Comment: @ZacharyK: *"I should have been more specific."* - this is definitely true. And you should be even more specific: What specific kind of attack you imagine for a local attacker which is made possible by using a broadcast address but is not possible without?

Comment: It's just for personal interest but le'ts suppose he wants to encrypt all personal & confidential files to demand a rescue. I also apologize for the non technical language as I've told i am still learning.

Comment: @ZacharyK: This broad attack description does not fit the criteria *"which is made possible by using a broadcast address but is not possible without"*. I would even say that it is not possible with broadcast at all. In harsher words: your attack description is just an enumeration of buzzwords without a deeper understanding what's possible in reality. Please specify a realistic attack which depends on broadcast.